# Ошибка Could not parse the remainder: ' 'css/style.css'' from 'static 'css/style.css''

Tags: django

Помогите исправить ошибку в  django 1.8
Сначала работало.Почему то после перезагрузки появилась ошибка

> TemplateSyntaxError at / 
>   Could not parse the remainder: ''css/style.css'' from 'static 'css/style.css''
>   Request Method:   GET 
>   Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/ 
>   Django Version:   1.8 Exception 
>   Type: TemplateSyntaxError
>   Exception Value:   Could not parse the remainder: ' 'css/style.css'' from 'static 'css/style.css''

**Файл settings:**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'post',
    'frontend',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'postman.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'postman.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'postman.sqlite3'),
    }
}


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

базовый шаблон

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ static 'css/style.css' }}" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<a href="{% url 'frontend.views.home' %}" class="logo">
Логотип
</a>
<body>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в ссылке должен быть темплейт тег для загрузки статики
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" type="text/css"/>`
Поправьте синтаксис и будет работать

Comment: вот я лоханулся!спасибо!